# Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'void' and 'void'

Tags: c#

I managed to get my above codes to work but i get the following error.
Tried googling and i sort of understand a little that its the datatype problem. 
But if i change the datatype for my above two functions, i'll get the same error.
What should i do?

*Trying to calculate the lexical density index in this case.

```
//For counting unique words
 private void UniqueWordCount(string fbStatus)
        {
            int count = 0;
            var countedWordList = new List<string>(100);
            var reg = new Regex(@"\w+");
            foreach (Match match in reg.Matches(fbStatus))
            {
                string word = match.Value.ToLower();
                if (!countedWordList.Contains(word))
                {
                    ++count;
                    countedWordList.Add(word);
                }
            }
            label_totaluniquewords.Text = count.ToString();
        }

//For counting total words

  private void SplitWords(string fbStatus)
        {
            int splitWords = fbStatus.Split(new char[] { ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count();
            label_totalwordcount.Text = splitWords.ToString();
        }

//For counting lexical density (trying to make this work...)
   private void CalculateLexicalDensity(string fbStatus)
        {
            int ld = 0;
            ld = (UniqueWordCount(fbStatus) / SplitWords(fbStatus)) * 100;
            label_lexicaldensity.Text = ld.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: `UniqueWordCount` and `SplitWords` don't return anything. What do you think you're dividing?

Comment: @SamuelLee I would calculate both word counts (unique and otherwise) starting with the array splitWords, so I can avoid splitting the string twice, saving some computation time.

Answer (score 4):

`SplitWords` does not return a value that it calculates. If you plan to return the count, add

```
return splitWords;
```

at the end of the function, and declare it `int`:

```
private int SplitWords(string fbStatus)
    {
        int splitWords = fbStatus.Split(new char[] { ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count();
        label_totalwordcount.Text = splitWords.ToString();
        return splitWords;
    }
```

Note, however, that your computation of percentage is likely to be off because of integer division. You should either return a `decimal`, or cast to `decimal` before applying division.

You could also change the order of operations

```
ld = 100 * UniqueWordCount(fbStatus) / SplitWords(fbStatus);
```

to get an integer result truncated to the highest whole percentage.

Comment: Your method is still declared as void.

Comment: I got this message: Since 'empTRUST.PostSummary.SplitWords(string)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression"

Comment: I did what you mentioned above and included "label_lexicaldensity.Text = ld.ToString();" however the result doesnt get posted to the label.

Comment: @SamuelLee Are you sure `CalculateLexicalDensity` gets invoked? Can you set a break point?

Comment: Hey yeah. i forgot to invoke it. thanks dude! Btw, how do i add a percentage behind the display?

Comment: @SamuelLee add `+"%"` after `ToString()`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the code to this:

```
//For counting unique words
 private int UniqueWordCount(string fbStatus)
        {
            int count = 0;
            var countedWordList = new List<string>(100);
            var reg = new Regex(@"\w+");
            foreach (Match match in reg.Matches(fbStatus))
            {
                string word = match.Value.ToLower();
                if (!countedWordList.Contains(word))
                {
                    ++count;
                    countedWordList.Add(word);
                }
            }
            label_totaluniquewords.Text = count.ToString();
            return count;
        }



private int SplitWords(string fbStatus)
        {
            int splitWords = fbStatus.Split(new char[] { ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count();
            label_totalwordcount.Text = splitWords.ToString();
            return splitWords;
        }

//For counting lexical density (trying to make this work...)
   private void CalculateLexicalDensity(string fbStatus)
        {
            decimal ld = 0;
            ld = ((decimal)UniqueWordCount(fbStatus) / (decimal)SplitWords(fbStatus)) * 100;
            label_lexicaldensity.Text = ld.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Got this message "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Hey pavel, i followed what you recommended but the result still doesn't get posted to the label

Comment: Ah yes, check out the edit. If you want to display the percentage as integer, do what @dasblinkenlight did.

Comment: Did so but the result still doeesn't get posted to the label.. why?

Answer (score 1):

---

### 1. Add a method to split the text

Since both UniqueCount and SplitWords are going to work on a list of words extracted from the original text, it makes sense to create a function for that.

This method takes a string with the text you want to work with, and returns an array of strings containing the words it has.

```
private string[] GetWords(string text)
{
    return text.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

---

### 2. Code your functions to work on the array

For counting unique words:

```
private int UniqueCount(string[] words)
{
    var foundWords = new List<string>();
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        string word = word.ToLower();
        if (!foundWords.Contains(word))
        {
            foundWords.Add(word);
        }
    }
    return foundWords.Length;
}
```

For counting total words:

```
private int Count(string[] words)
{
    return words.Length;
}
```

For lexical density:

```
private double CalculateLexicalDensity(string[] words)
{
    return ((double)UniqueCount(words) / (double)Count(words));
}
```

Note: neither of these update the labels, I want to separate that concern into antoher method.

---

### 3. Create a method to update the labels

This method calls the others and updates the labels

Note: I strongly believe that fbStatus should be a parameter.

```
private void UpdateLabels(string fbStatus)
{
    var words = GetWords(fbStatus);     
    label_totalwordcount = Count(words).ToString();
    label_totaluniquewords.Text = UniqueCount(words).ToString();
    label_lexicaldensity = (CalculateLexicalDensity(words) * 100).ToString() + "%";
}
```

---

### 4. Get rid of redundant computation

For this we have a few options:

**4.A. Mix concerns again:**

In this case I'll fuse the method CalculateLexicalDensity into UpdateLabels so I avoid executing twice both UniqueCount and Count.

```
private void UpdateLabels(string fbStatus)
{
    var words = GetWords(fbStatus);     
    int wordCount = Count(words);
    int uniqueWordCount = UniqueWordCount(words);
    double lexicalDensity = ((double)uniqueWordCount / (double)wordCount);
    label_totalwordcount = wordCount.ToString();
    label_totaluniquewords.Text = uniqueWordCount.ToString();
    label_lexicaldensity = (lexicalDensity * 100).ToString() + "%";
}
```

**4.B. Use a tuple as return type:**

In this case I'll fuse Count, UniqueCount and CalculateLexicalDensity into one method, this will allow - again - to avoid executing twice both UniqueCount and Count. Since this method would need to return three values, it will return a Tuple [It could also be a custom type].

```
private UpdateLabels(string fbStatus)
{
    var words = GetWords(fbStatus);     
    var info = Process(words);
    label_totalwordcount = info.Item1.ToString();
    label_totaluniquewords.Text = info.Item2.ToString();
    label_lexicaldensity = (info.Item3 * 100).ToString() + "%";
}

private Tuple<int, int, double> Process(string[] words)
{
    int wordCount = Count(words);
    int uniqueWordCount = UniqueWordCount(words);
    double lexicalDensity = ((double)uniqueWordCount / (double)wordCount);
    return new Tuple<int, int, double>(wordCount, uniqueWordCount, lexicalDensity);
}
```

Since this option keeps concerns separate, I would prefer this one. Yet in the ocurrence that you can't (or you don't want) to use Tuple, you can use a custom type... for this case I prefer a struct...

**4.C. Use a struct as return type:**

```
struct LexicalInfo
{
    public int WordCount;
    public int UniqueWordCount;
    public int LexicalDensity;
}
```

Using this struct, the code would be:

```
private UpdateLabels(string fbStatus)
{
    var words = GetWords(fbStatus);     
    var info = Process(words);
    label_totalwordcount = info.WordCount.ToString();
    label_totaluniquewords.Text = info.UniqueWordCount.ToString();
    label_lexicaldensity = (info.LexicalDensity * 100).ToString() + "%";
}

private LexicalInfo Process(string[] words)
{
    int wordCount = Count(words);
    int uniqueWordCount = UniqueWordCount(words);
    double lexicalDensity = ((double)uniqueWordCount / (double)wordCount);
    return new LexicalInfo()
            {
                WordCount = wordCount,
                UniqueWordCount = uniqueWordCount,
                LexicalDensity = lexicalDensity
            };
}
```

Futhermore if we are goint to use a struct...

**4.D. Use a struct to do the computation:**

Note: In this case, it may al well be a class.

```
struct LexicalInfo
{
    private int wordCount;
    private int uniqueWordCount;

    public LexicalInfo(string text)
    {
        var words = GetWords(text);
        wordCount = Count(words);
        uniqueWordCount = UniqueCount(words);
    }

private string[] GetWords(string text)
{
    return text.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}

    private int UniqueCount(string[] words)
{
    var foundWords = new List<string>();
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        string word = word.ToLower();
        if (!foundWords.Contains(word))
        {
            foundWords.Add(word);
        }
    }
    return foundWords.Length;
}

private int Count(string[] words)
{
    return words.Length;
}

    public int WordCount
    {
        get
        {
            return wordCount;
        }
    }

    public int UniqueWordCount
    {
        get
        {
            return uniqueWordCount;
        }
    }

    public double LexicalDensity
    {
        get
        {
            return ((double)uniqueWordCount / (double)wordCount);
        }
    }
}

//----

private UpdateLabels(string fbStatus)
{
    var info = new LexicalInfo(words);
    label_totalwordcount = info.WordCount.ToString();
    label_totaluniquewords.Text = info.UniqueWordCount.ToString();
    label_lexicaldensity = (info.LexicalDensity * 100).ToString() + "%";
}
```

---

### 5. Optimization

I'll take the final code (the one using the struct for the computation), and work on it.

We have two methods that has only one line (the methods are GetWords and Count), I'll get rid of them and replace the call by the method body:

```
struct LexicalInfo
{
    private int wordCount;
    private int uniqueWordCount;

    public LexicalInfo(string text)
    {
        var words = text.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        wordCount = words.Length;
        uniqueWordCount = UniqueCount(words);
    }

    private int UniqueCount(string[] words)
{
    var foundWords = new List<string>();
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        string word = word.ToLower();
        if (!foundWords.Contains(word))
        {
            foundWords.Add(word);
        }
    }
    return foundWords.Length;
}

    public int WordCount
    {
        get
        {
            return wordCount;
        }
    }

    public int UniqueWordCount
    {
        get
        {
            return uniqueWordCount;
        }
    }

    public double LexicalDensity
    {
        get
        {
            return ((double)uniqueWordCount / (double)wordCount);
        }
    }
}

//----

    private UpdateLabels(string fbStatus)
{
    var info = new LexicalInfo(words);
    label_totalwordcount = info.WordCount.ToString();
    label_totaluniquewords.Text = info.UniqueWordCount.ToString();
    label_lexicaldensity = (info.LexicalDensity * 100).ToString() + "%";
}
```

---

### 6. Linq?

If we can use Linq, we can replace UniqueCount with a single line:

```
struct LexicalInfo
{
    private int wordCount;
    private int uniqueWordCount;

    public LexicalInfo(string text)
    {
        var words = text.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        wordCount = words.Length;
        uniqueWordCount = words.Distinct().Count();
    }

    public int WordCount
    {
        get
        {
            return wordCount;
        }
    }

    public int UniqueWordCount
    {
        get
        {
            return uniqueWordCount;
        }
    }

    public double LexicalDensity
    {
        get
        {
            return ((double)uniqueWordCount / (double)wordCount);
        }
    }
}

//----

private UpdateLabels(string fbStatus)
{
    var info = new LexicalInfo(fbStatus);
    label_totalwordcount = info.WordCount.ToString();
    label_totaluniquewords.Text = info.UniqueWordCount.ToString();
    label_lexicaldensity = (info.LexicalDensity * 100).ToString() + "%";
}
```

---

### 7. Testing and Fixing

I have used the following text for a test:

> ESTE ES UN TEXTO QUE HE ESCRITO EN ESPAÑOL. ESTE TEXTO FUE ESCRITO PARA DEMOSTRACIÓN. ESTE TEXTO REPITE ALGUNAS DE SUS PALABRAS Y ALGUNAS OTRAS NO.

La salida fue:

```
WordCount = 28
UniqueWordCount = 21
LexicalDensity = 75%
```

Yet, inspecting the code reveals that we are counting punctuation marks as part of the words (ie. The code sees `ESPAÑOL` and `ESPAÑOL.` as two diferent words because of the punctuation mark).

You may use the regular expression for a quick fix, in order to do that replace the constructor of LexicalInfo with this:

```
    public LexicalInfo(string text)
    {
        var words = from match in (new Regex(@"\w+")).Matches(text).Cast<Match>() select match.Value;
        wordCount = words.Count();
        uniqueWordCount = words.Distinct().Count();
        Console.WriteLine(words.Distinct().ToArray());
    }
```

After the change the output is:

```
WordCount = 28
UniqueWordCount = 20
LexicalDensity = 71.4285714285714%
```

You may want to format the LexicalDensity, for example changing the following line:

```
     label_lexicaldensity = (info.LexicalDensity * 100).ToString() + "%";
```

To the this:

```
    label_lexicaldensity = string.Format("{0:P2}", info.LexicalDensity);
```

Will yield this:

```
WordCount = 28
UniqueWordCount = 20
LexicalDensity = 71.43 %
```

Note: using string.Format is affected by the Culture on which it is executed. If you don't want to change with the culture you can specify one, for instace InvariantCulture:

```
    label_lexicaldensity = string.Format("{0:P2}", info.LexicalDensity, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

Using another test text, I found that I have lost the ability to detect caps. The text is

> Este es otro texto escrito en español, el objetivo de este texto es probar las mayúsculas al repetir texto.

In this case, the code sees `Este` and `este` as two different words. This is another easy fix with Linq, change this line:

```
        uniqueWordCount = words.Distinct().Count();
```

To this one:

```
        uniqueWordCount = (from word in words select word.ToLower()).Distinct().Count();
```